# unicode support works in moderncv but not in article documentclass

Tags: moderncv, unicode, article

I honestly don't understand this. Why do I have unicode support when i use the `moderncv` documentclass, but not when i use the one of `article` ? For compilation, I use `latexmk -xelatex f.tex`

code:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontenc}

\firstname{}
\lastname{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}  
ää--llll
\end{document}
```

result:

[image: moderncv-unicode-works]

code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}  
ää--llll
\end{document}
```

result:

[image: article-unicode-doesnt-work]

Comment: Did you try adding `\usepackage{fontspec}`?

Comment: You need to load `fontspec`.

Comment: Thanks both of you, that fixed the problem. Since @user93559 was first, would you consider morphing your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using XeLaTeX you should use the `fontspec` package instead of the `fontenc` package.

In other words the following code should produce the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \pagestyle{empty}  
  ää--llll
\end{document}
```